# Getting ModelState or ViewData from UrlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I think the title is clear. I need to capture `ModelState` or `ViewData` inside an extension method for `UrlHelper` class. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the title is clear. I need to capture ModelState or ViewData
>   inside an extension method for UrlHelper class

You can't. An UrlHelper doesn't have this information. For example you have an UrlHelper instance in your controller where it's too early to talk about any ViewData. Use an extension for HtmlHelper instead:

```
public static void SomeExtension(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var viewData = html.ViewData;
}
```

and if you need to get an UrlHelper inside an extension method for HtmlHelper:

```
public static void SomeExtension(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
}
```